# Service Dashboard OAuth client invalid scope

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

In my **service broker's catalog endpoint**, I have defined a `dashboard_client` like below.

```
"dashboard_client":{
  "id":"test-client-id",
  "secret":"test-client-secret",
  "redirect_uri":"https://dashboard.cf.myorg.com"
}
```

In my **service dashboard application** I am using the client id defined above to initiate the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow as prescribed in [CF Dashboard SSO documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/dashboard-sso.html).

Everything works fine (CF `authorization_endpoint` redirects to dashboard with auth code and dashboard gets access token from `token_endpoint`) if the client requests for the minimum scopes `cloud_controller_service_permissions.read` and `openid`. e.g.

```
https://login.cf.myorg.com/oauth/authorize?
    response_type=code&
    client_id=test-client-id&
    scope=openid%20cloud_controller_service_permissions.read&
    redirect_uri=https://dashboard.cf.myorg.com/auth
```

However, if the client requests for additional scopes `cloud_controller.read` and/or `cloud_controller.write` (which is also mentioned in the Dashboard SSO documentation), `authorization_endpoint` redirects to dashboard with an error `cloud_controller.read is invalid. Please use a valid scope name in the request`.

CF version 2.80.0.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/identity/uaa/oauth/UaaAuthorizationRequestManager.java#L213) line in UAA which is the show stopper here:

Adding `cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write` to the authorities (must be in authorities and scope) of the client and then updating the service broker via `cf update-service-broker` should fix that.

Comment: Thanks, yes. Cloud Controller creates the OAuth client with only `openid` and `cloud_controller_service_permissions.read` scopes by default. I had to subsequently request a UAA admin to add `cloud_controller.read` scope to the OAuth client created by Cloud Controller.